chromium and opera work with mictests.com, firefox fails
I use linux mint 20.1
When I try to use mictests.com on firefox, test fails. Firefox says this: Testing failed because your microphone could not capture any sounds. Please make sure your microphone is not muted and try again.
arecord/aread work:
arecord -f cd -d 20 --device="hw:0,0" cica.wav
aplay cica.wav
All other mic tests behave identical, do not work on firefox, but work on chromium/opera.
I could not find any hint in the web.
In the mean time solved, see my comment below.
I assume, the fact, that I used chromium and opera to test the microphone fixed the error also in firefox. If somebody understands this kind of problem, it would be useful, if he/she enlightened us.

Ask on mint forums. It works just fine here on Fedora.

After having waited, the voice regulator/input devices on linux control screen went green/checked (upper right part of the screen), and since that mictests.com works also on firefox.

Congratulations!  You can now write and possibly earn upvotes for your own answer.  Welcome to U&L.SE
